# Creating Boundaries to prevent player from moving into in java

Tags: java, boundary

In the Game I'm going to have a set path of `JButtons`. I also have an Array which holds all and only the values of the `JButtons` I want the player to be able to move onto.

```
    JButton[] x = new JButton[71];
    x[0] = y[0];
    x[1] = y[15];
    x[2] = y[16];
    x[3] = y[31];
    x[4] = y[32];
    x[5] = y[47];
    x[6] = y[62];
    x[7] = y[93];
    x[8] = y[63];
    x[9] = y[78];
    x[10] = y[108];
    x[11] = y[168];
    x[12] = y[183];
    x[13] = y[184];
    x[14] = y[153];
    x[15] = y[123];
    x[16] = y[138];
    x[17] = y[197];
    x[18] = y[195];
    x[19] = y[185];
    x[20] = y[186];
    x[21] = y[171];
    x[22] = y[172];
    x[23] = y[173];
```

I also have another array which holds every single value of the `JButtons` in my `Map`.

```
y = new JButton[225];
    for (int j = 0; j < 225; j++) {
        y[j] = new JButton();
        y[j].addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(y[j]);
    }
```

Using this code, how do I prevent the player from moving off the desired path/JButtons and stay on that singular path?

Comment: I really don't get the question :( "prevent the player from moving off the desired path/JButtons"? do you want to prevent him moving the mouse or what? how does he set the current position and how does he move?

Answer (score 0):

Create a point that follows the button, if the point strikes a certain point on the grid (in this case, your bounds) than flip the x/y-dir or set the speed to 0.

```
Point point = new Point(xloc, yLoc);
if (point.getX() >= bounds) {
    flipSpeed/stopSpeedHere 
}
```

Also you can probably use a forLoop, and just iterate through all that code instead of just typing it out.